# C++ iostreams not working when calling from Java through jni

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, iostream

I have a c++ library that is called from java side through java-native-interface . The used java version is AmazonCorretto_11.07 and the operating system Ubuntu 18.04 . The problem is that I have some logging code that is running fine when pure c++ is used. However, when the code is called through jni the iostream get stuck immediately when some number is inserted into stream. For example the following code prints fine `std::cerr << "hello world " << std::endl`. However, the following code  `std::cerr << "hello world " << 2.0 << "hello world" << std::endl` prints only the first "hello world" and gets "stuck" when the number is inserted. I have also tried the Boost logger but the behaviour is the same. Everything works normally when pure c++ is used, but when calling through jni from java AmazonCorretto11 the problem occcurs.

Comment: The first thing you should investigate is where it is getting stuck, not at a high-level, but deeper into the code.  Debuggers can break into a "stuck" program, where you can then see the call stack to get to the place in the code that is causing the issue.  Now *how* to solve the problem is a different story.